# want to read file line by line and then want to cut the line on delimiter

Tags: perl, shell

```
cat $INPUT_FILE| while read LINE
do
abc=cut -d ',' -f 4 $LINE
```

Comment: not clear what you want. Do you want to port that shell code to Perl?

Comment: Can you give more information on what kind of output you want? Maybe an example of input and output. Also, do you need it in Perl??

Comment: my input file looks like this: 1,a,x,
2,b,y

Comment: and i want to use the forth column to fetch some values from data base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use command substitution if you want the output of a command saved in a variable.

POSIX shell (`sh`):

```
while read -r LINE
do
    abc=$(cut -d ',' -f 4 "$LINE")
done < "$INPUT_FILE"
```

If you're using a legacy Bourne shell, use backticks instead of the preferred `$()`:

```
    abc=`cut -d ',' -f 4 "$LINE"`
```

In some shells, you may not need to use an external utility.

Bash, ksh, zsh:

```
while read -r LINE
do
    IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 abc remainder <<< "$LINE"
done < "$INPUT_FILE"
```

or

```
while read -r LINE
do
    IFS=, read -r -a array <<< "$LINE"
    abc=${array[3]}
done < "$INPUT_FILE"
```

or

```
saveIFS=$IFS
while read -r LINE
do
    IFS=,
    array=($LINE)
    IFS=$saveIFS
    abc=${array[3]}
done < "$INPUT_FILE"
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl:

```
cat $INPUT_FILE | perl -ne '{my @fields = split /,/; print $fields[3];}'
```

Comment: @rodion - was the only thing that i could make sense of. Could be wrong

Comment: The -a and -F flags make that even simpler: cat $INPUT_FILE | perl -n -a -F, -e 'print $F[3]'

Comment: Don't abuse `cat; use `perl -ne '...' $INPUT_FILE`.

Comment: @Jonathan - using cat and a pipe allows one the flexibility of changing the input source easily, which is why I have a habit of usingh it even when not strictly speaking necessary. Additional minor benefit is that the Perl eval code is at the END of the line, easily allowing me to edit last line without skipping over the file name. It's a good point that you CAN do `perl -ne '$code' $input_file` if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Bash:

```
while read line ; do
    cut -d, -f4 <<<"$line"
done < $INPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight Perl:

```
open (INPUT_FILE, "<$INPUT_FILE") or die ("Could not open $INPUT_FILE");
while (<INPUT_FILE>) {
    @fields = split(/,/, $_);
    $use_this_field_value = $fields[3];
    # do something with field value here
}
close (INPUT_FILE);
```

Comment: If invoked with `$INPUT_FILE` on the command line, you don't need to explicitly open or close the file - just use `while (<>)` ...